# UNCSS keeps aborting with "src files were empty" message

Tags: gruntjs, uncss

I keep getting this error with UNCSS: `'Warning: Destination (dist/css/main.css) not written because src files were empty. Use --force to contine. Aborted due to warnings.`

I believe it's running the task fine and is set up properly. I can use grunt for other things.

In gruntfile.js, I've included: `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');`
and

```
  uncss: {
    dist: {
        files: {
          'dist/css/main2.css': ['../index.html']                                           
        }
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure what's wrong, but I think it's the pathing, but that's just how it is. I'm also using SCSS, so maybe it needs a raw css as `SRC`? I've tried reinstalling PhantomJS and the raw UNCSS without Grunt, but I'm going no where! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
It wasn't necessarily the pathing, but how the pathing was presented.

I was using

```
  files: {
      'dist/css/main2.css': ['../index.html']                                           
  }
```

I switched to

```
 files: [       
      { src: 'index.html', dest: 'dist/css/main.css' }
 ]
```

Here, the `src` & `dest` are declared.

This blog helped me [deanhume.com](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/automatically-removing-unused-css-using-grunt/6101).
The github/NPM documentation didn't work for me, but this guy's did. I hope this helps someone!